# Invalid hook error when attempting to access previous prop value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code. I would like my log to fire if the value changes.

```
const usePrevious = (value) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}

const App = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const previousValue = usePrevious(props.value)
    if (previousValue !== props.value) {
     console.log('fire')
    };
  }, []);

  return <div />
}
```

For some reason I am getting this error: "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."

I'm unsure why. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to accomplish with this code. The effect runs only once so there is no previous value, `previousValue !== props.value` will *nearly* always be true. With the `usePrevious` pattern you also usually use it in the function body, but it's a hook so it can be used within other react hooks without issue. Are you sure this is where the error is?

Comment: `usePrevious` is not in a component, but it calls `useEffect`. It's called inside a `useEffect` already so not sure the expected behavior here.

Comment: So this works (and is the suggested way of handling previous props) if it's not inside useEffect. But inside useEffect, it's creating problems. It's a hook.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I believe the error is that this line:
`const previousValue = usePrevious(props.value)` cannot be used within a hook (useEffect) in your case.

If you move that line above and outside of your useEffect hook it should fix it for you.

https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#breaking-the-rules-of-hooks